# make a bot that when you have .gg/huggies in your status it gives you a role? Pls

Tags: discord

I don't know coding, can you please give me the code? I need it for my server, I tried using the code from ChatGPT and Bard AI but it seems not to work

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', async (oldPresence, newPresence) => {

    const role = newPresence.guild.roles.cache.get("941814488917766145");

    const member = newPresence.member

    const activities = member.presence.activities[0];

  

    if (activities && (activities.state.includes( ".gg/testing" ) || activities.state.includes("discord.gg/huggies" ))) {

      return newPresence.member.roles.add(role)

    } else {

      if(member.roles.cache.get(role.id)) {

        newPresence.member.roles.remove(role)

      }

    }

})
```